# Enter and Exit Transition between Activities not running smoothly in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-animation, androidx

**What I want to do**

Making a smooth transition/animation between `SplashActivity` & `LoginActivity`.

(Both activities using androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity)

**Project Dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    with(window) {
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)

        exitTransition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    }
    //Handler codes waiting for around 700ms...
}

fun startLoginActivity() {
    // Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions
                                   .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this)
                                   .toBundle())
    } else {
         //Swap without transition
         startActivity(intent)
    }
    finishAfterTransition()
}
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    with(window) {
        requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)

        allowEnterTransitionOverlap = true
        enterTransition = Slide(Gravity.TOP)
        exitTransition = Explode()
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.transaction(now = true) {
            replace(R.id.loginContainer, LoginFragment.newInstance())
        }
    }
}
```

**What happened**

1. When calling `SplashActivity.startLoginActivity()`, window fades and closes, and re-open with `LoginActivity`. This is not what I expected
2. When I close LoginActivity, view components in `LoginFragment` stays there in the background, but without the window. This should not happen.

Any idea on how to fix the problem?

*Note:*

Both in the `SplashActivity` & `LoginActivity`, I could not use Classes from `androidx.transition.*`.

It is because of `androidx.AppCompatActivity` is returning android.view.window, and I have to use Classes from `android.transition.*`, which is working but I'm not sure if it's the causes of the bugs.